# GUI components not submitted when publishing to gallery: Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

When I published an app to the google app script gallery for spreadsheet tools, it failed to upload the GUI builder components as well. Do you know how I should go about remedying this?

I just get this:

Invalid argument: resourceName (line 37)

When trying to execute the code. Line 37 corresponds to where the code exists which loads the GUI builder component in to the UI app. I was going to rewrite the code and programmatically create the visual elements, but it seems like that would defeat the purpose!

Many thanks,

Eamonn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the GUI Builder falls short when you try to share it. Being through the Script Gallery [or as a library](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=623). There's no way at all to export it and import in another script.

And that the reason why I never use it. Sometimes I play with it just to make fast mock ups to see if how an idea will actually look on Apps Script, but never as the real thing I'm going to develop.

You should open an issue report on the [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), since publishing on the Gallery should really work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hmmm ok. I will do it from the code then. At least I know why it's not working now :)

Comment: On another related note, do you know how to set the position of a Label. Is it done via CSS? There are methods to set image locations, but not labels.

Comment: Issue reported. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1551&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Comment: What do you mean on how to position? Widgets are placed depending on the panel you put them in, e.g. a VerticalPanel, HorizonalPanel, a Grid and so on. If you want to place it precisely, you should use the `AbsolutePanel` and use its [add(widget,left,top)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_absolutepanel#add) method.

Comment: Ah, ok. It must implicitly do that in the UI builder. Thanks for the hint. I'm porting everything over now.

Comment: GUI Builder components can be stored in a library and returned from a function in the library.

Comment: But will the library included in the published script remain included when a user installs the the script from the gallery? I doubt, but if it does, then yes, this is a workaround.